# Chrome Dev Tools. How to check the outgoing size of request when there is no content-length header?

Tags: request, upload, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to see actual outgoing traffic size (per request) in Chrome (or other browser).
`Content-Length` is not provided on some requests.